# Implementation of the board in an Android board game

Tags: android

1. How can I implement a board for a board game on Android, with the board having clickable cells and movable pieces in it?
2. Can I use map editors like TiLed? How?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want to do, is to use a library that provides support for games. There are libraries that are able to parse TMX files, that are created by TiLed and other editors.

The library / game engine that I like to use ist AndEngine (http://www.andengine.org). A lot of things will be taken care of by this library, so that you can concentrate on creating your game. AndEngine is able to use TMX maps.